# elasticsearch bulk delete by custom field values

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm building app with elasticsearch (5.4) and everything was going well until I try to delete several documents by field values. My x-ndjson looks like this:

```
{ "delete" : {} }
{ "id" : "109991" }
{ "delete" : {} }
{ "id" : "109992" }
{ "delete" : {} }
{ "id" : "109993" }
                        <- empty line
```

and i am POSTing it on http://localhost:9200/someindex/sometype/_bulk, but it responds with **"Malformed action/metadata line [2], expected START_OBJECT or END_OBJECT but found [VALUE_NUMBER]"**.
Note that my "id" is my custom field, not the _id.

Is something missing in my request?
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you need to use [Delete By Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html) for this.

```
POST index/_delete_by_query
{
   "query": {
    "terms": {
       "id": [
          109991,
          109992
       ]
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Work like a charm. Thank you savior!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: @Richa can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49247236/elasticsearch-how-to-delete-docs-if-field-exists.

Comment: @Richa, the same sort of request doesn't work for me. It gives a 200 response with a response body containing `took` which randomly says 1, 39, etc. while the `deleted` field in the response is always 0. What could be the problem?

Comment: Worked! Seems I was having a mistake with the `_id` in the query.