# ElasticSearch how to DELETE docs if field exists?

Tags: database, elasticsearch

I want to delete all documents where a certain **field** exists

I tried to POST to the *_delete_by_query* API

```
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "exists":"field_name" }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

That's giving me this *query malformed* error:

```
{
"error": {
    "root_cause": [
        {
            "type": "parsing_exception",
            "reason": "[exists] query malformed, no start_object after query name",
            "line": 1,
            "col": 37
        }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "[exists] query malformed, no start_object after query name",
    "line": 1,
    "col": 37
},
"status": 400
}
```

How can I delete all docs if *field* exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your query:

You don't have to use `bool` query, just use below query and it should work.

```
{
"query": {
  "exists": {
    "field": "name"
  }
 }
}
```

Read [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/query-dsl-exists-query.html) for more details.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to wrap the exists in a bool.
Try this

```
 {
  "query": { 
    "exists": {
      "field": "field_name"
    }
  }
}
```